# how to write Trigger on 2 object

Tags: apex, trigger

***we have 2 objects Account and Dsignation

parent object: Account

Child object: Designation

Relationship: Lookup(Field name `Account__c` on Designation object)

If an Account has Designation with Title CEO(Field name `Title__c`) then the Account field  "Area__c" cannot be blank

// Trigger

```java
trigger demo on Account (after update) {
   if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate ){
       system.debug('hello buddy');
       demohandler.validationdemo(trigger.old);
   }
}
```

// handler class

```java
public class demohandler {
    public static void validationdemo(List<Account> acc){
        Set<Id> idSet = new Set<Id>();
        for(Account acc1: acc){
            idSet.add(acc1.id);
        }

        List<Account> accList = [Select id, Area__c,(select id, Title__c from Designations__r) from Account where Id IN: idSet];
        for(Account act:Designation__c.){
            for(Designation__c deg:accList.act){  
                if(deg.Title__c == 'CEO' && act.Area__c == ''){
                    act.addError('Area should not be blank');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but i am getting an error. does any one provide me a right solutons

Comment: Hello Singh_25. Welcome to SFSE (Salesforce StackExchange), could you please clarify what is the error, what you have attempted and where you got stuck? May I also suggest you to look into [ask]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use ***trigger.new*** instead of ***trigger.old*** and ***before*** trigger  .

Also  You must use initial ***trigger.new*** list in order to add error to Account record

And your code will look like this :

```
trigger demo on Account (before update) {
   if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate ){
     demohandler.validationdemo(trigger.new);
   }
}
```

and handler

```
 public class demohandler { 
   public static void validationdemo(List<Account> triggerNewList){
      List<Account> accListWithDesignations = [Select id, Area__c,(select id,Title__c from Designations__r) from Account where Id IN : triggerNewList];
      Map<Id,List<Designation__c> > mapWithDesignations = new Map<Id,List<Designation__c>> ();
       for (Account act : accListWithDesignations ) {
          mapWithDesignations.put(act.Id, act.Designations__r);
       }
      for(Account act : triggerNewList){
          for(Designation__c deg : mapWithDesignations.get(act.Id)){  
             if(deg.Title__c == 'CEO'  && (act.Area__c == null || act.Area__c == '') ){
                act.addError('Area should not be blank');
             }
        
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: why you have been used map instead of Set any particular reasons.  It is giving error also Map variables does not exist

Comment: @singh_25 I have updated answer
Please check now

Comment: but how can i check my trigger is working fine or not??

Comment: @singh_25 
You should create a Designation record with Title__c == 'CEO' for an account.
and then try to update the account Area__c field  to empty string or null.
You will see your error.

Comment: hello Dehnerys i think trigger should be written on another object also because this is not working properly

Comment: @singh_25 What exactly is not working for you ? 
You do not see the error ?

Comment: yes when i put area should be blank its doesnt showing anything

Comment: Review the errors on this page.
demo: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors Class.demohandler.validationdemo: line 12, column 1 Trigger.demo: line 4, column 1

Comment: these errors i got

Comment: @singh_25 . you MUST change "after update" on "before update"

Comment: no, you havent understand the questions properly .Trigger should be written on two object Account and designations also we have written trigger only on  Account